# How would I go about moving my blue bar Image to cover all of the gray area?

Tags: java, android

[image]

As the image shows, the blue image here does not completely move to the top. I would like to be able to move this blue bar to be on the border of the black bar above, but the small gray area is there and I cannot move it in the graphical layout.

EDIT: here is the XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F3F3F3" >



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="124dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedcorner"
        android:ems="10"
        tools:ignore="TextFields" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/bluebars" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT: My temporary solution** I programmatically changed how my image is aligned.

```
ImageView iv;
iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
iv.getLayoutParams().height = 265;
```

I call this the temporary solution because this is what I'll work with until I find a better way (I'm a newb to RelativeLayout) and this fix might cause problems on bigger/smaller devices. So it is not recommended, but it'll do until I find a better way.

Comment: The empty area at the top is the application title bar.  Hide it using Theme or `requestWindowFeature`.  Also this image is clearly from Eclipse UI builder - it's not always accurate.  You must test by running your app.

Comment: can you post your layout xml?

Comment: sure Hamidu, i'll edit my post for you.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in Application Tag in your menifest file.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
```

And *Remove* this If you have added in your code:

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: I did as you stated and it still doesn't work. I believe the problem is the actual alignment within the RelativeLayout.

Comment: Have you tried it by running the app in real device?

Comment: Of course, it's how I test it every time. 

I should Tell you that I just fixed the problem..

well, I wouldn't say fixed.. but maybe I made some compromises that will cause me problems later, I don't know, but here is what I did.


I programmatically changed it.

`ImageView iv;`
`iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview1);`
`iv.getLayoutParams().height = 265;`

and this aligns it perfectly to my liking.

I guess I should ask my self "will this look out of place on bigger or smaller devices since I changed it programmatically..

Comment: Yes Its good that you found a solution fro now. But in Android you must have to found universal solution that runs equally in all devices.

Comment: Yeah. I'll come back to this problem later.  Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the `onCreate()`  of your activity.

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

This should hide the titlebar as Aleks G mentioned.

Make sure to do this before `setContentView()`

Comment: I tried.. the app crashes when I add this code inside the onCreate().

Comment: this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); set before setContentView(R.layout.acitivity_search);

Comment: I did that this time, the error is gone, but my image is still as you see in the picture above.